# Button switching binding event bug

Tags: javascript, html, dom

When getRes is reassigned, the printed value of num remains unchanged, but this problem does not occur when rebinding the DOM click event. What causes this problem?

I tried switching arrow functions, using other ordinary function bindings, etc. I guessed that the problem was related to the DOM underlying binding event mechanism.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<body>
  <button id="btn" onclick="getRes">button</button>
  <script>
    function getRes(resolve, num) {
      console.log(num);
      resolve();
    }
    async function start() {
      console.log('start');
      for (let i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        await new Promise(function(resolve) {
          getRes = getRes.bind(this, resolve, i);
          // document.querySelector("#btn").onclick = getRes.bind(this, resolve, i);
        })
      }
      console.log('end')
    }
    start();
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This is an X/Y problem. What are you trying to do and why are you even using async/promises? Why the inline click AND onclick? Why not addEventListener as you should?

Comment: This code is largely nonsense. Do you not have realistic one? `await`-ing a promise that doesn't ever resolve doesn't do anything. So, the loop is "stuck". But even if it wasn't, then chaining `.bind()` on the same function as shown here would not *replace* the bound arguments but *append* to them. `f.bind(null, 1).bind(null, 2)()` will effectively call `f(1, 2)`

Answer (score -1):

Removed the **incorrect onclick** attribute in the button element and added a proper event listener in the script.
Changed the way **getRes** function is called in the loop inside start function.
Now, when you click the button, it should log numbers from **0 to 8** in the console and then print 'start' and 'end' accordingly.

```js
function getRes(resolve, num) {
  console.log(num);
  resolve();
}

document.querySelector("#btn").onclick = async() => {
  await start();
}

async function start() {
  console.log('start');
  for (let i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    await new Promise(function(resolve) {
      getRes(resolve, i);
    })
  }
  console.log('end')
}
```

```html
<button id="btn">button</button>
```